# Incorrect decimal to hexadecimal conversion - C

Tags: c, hex

I wrote this function from a pseudocode I found, which should convert decimal input into hexadecimal number. Well it does that, but in incorrect order, like for example, for decimal number 195 I get 3C, insted of C3.

```
int temp=0;
int i=0;
while(decimal!=0)
{
    temp = decimal % 16;
    if( temp < 10)
        temp =temp + 48;
    else
        temp = temp + 55;
    array[i++]= temp;
    decimal = decimal / 16;
}
```

Comment: Set `i` near the end of the array `array[]` and use `i--`.  Also likely want a `array[size-1] = '\0';` someplace.  Suggest a `do { ...  } while (decimal);` loop to handle `decimal == 0`.

Comment: @rici yes of course, I didn't look into this any longer than 10 seconds.

Comment: One way to ensure the correct letters  is to refer to positions in a const char array "0123456789ABCDEF".

Comment: A piece of paper and a pencil should help here. Sidenote: don't use "magic" numbers such as 48 and 55, but rather `'0'` and `'A' - 10`, which shows clearly your intention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a decimal to a hexadecimal number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928517/converting-a-decimal-to-a-hexadecimal-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save yourself some time like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
// ...
sprintf(hexStr,"%X",decimal);   // or, "%#X" if you want prefix
```

unless, this is homework for a programming class.   in which case you should really just work it out on whiteboard or paper, i'm sure you'll see your mistake.